# replace lines in the original file from another file by line number

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed, regular-expression

**Original Text:**

```
yes
no
approved
declined
```

**Second Text**

```
1111 1
333 4
```

`1` and `4` is the line numbers which i would like to replace in the original Text

**Output:**

```
1111
no
approved
333
```

**how to handle this**

Comment: Shouldn’t line 1 have turned into `1111` ?

Comment: @JeffSchaller edited, were a mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short **awk** approach:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$2]=$1; next }FNR in a{ $0=a[FNR] }1' file2 file1
```

- `a[$2]=$1` - capturing 1st field `$1` values using 2nd field `$2` value as array `a` index (when processing the first input file i.e. `file2`)
- `$0=a[FNR]` - substitute the whole line with the value in regard to the current record number `FNR` (when processing the `file1`)

---

The output:

```
1111
no
approved
333
```

Comment: :D amazing awk usage :D no way with you. hahah

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη, you're welcome

Answer (score 0):

If you like program-generating programs, you could use awk to create a sed script:

```
awk '{printf "%dc\\\n%s\n", $2, $1}' < second  | sed -f - original
```

if your sed accepts stdin for the script, or:

```
awk '{printf "%dc\\\n%s\n", $2, $1}' < second > tempfile &&
sed -f tempfile original &&
rm tempfile
```

if your sed does not accept stdin for the script.

The intermediate sed script looks like this with your sample input:

```
1c\
1111
4c\
333
```